# rerun a failed spark job in a spark application which has multiple action(job)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Consider I have a spark application and has two action which leads to two spark job.

```
//spark Application 
     //Spark Job1
       ....
       errorCount.saveAsTextFile(errorCountOpPath);

    //spark Job2    
      ......
      debugCount.saveAsTextFile(debCountOpPath);
```

now lets assume we launched spark application on Yarn using spark submit command. job1 is successful but job2 has failed.

now I want to rerun job2 since it has failed.

when I try to re launch spark application on Yarn using spark submit command both job1 and job2 are getting triggered. but I don't want job1 to get triggered since it has already been completed successfully.

Is there any way by which I can make sure only failed job of a spark application will run?

Comment: Did you get the answer for your question. I'm looking for the solution for similar kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the check on your saveAsTextFile call like below :-

```
val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(conf)
val exists = fs.exists(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/path/on/hdfs/to/SUCCESS.txt"))
if(!exists) {
// write the the file
}
```